# xacro.py generates empty urdf file

Tags: urdf, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using following command to convert *.urdf.xacro to *.urdf in ROS indigo,ubuntu 14.04:

```
rosrun xacro xacro.py a.urdf.xacro > a.urdf
```

also

```
rosrun xacro xacro.py -o a.urdf a.urdf.xacro
```

content of a.urdf.xacro(just for test):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
<property name="base_mass" value="3.7000" />
<xacro:macro name="hunter">
    <xacro:macro name="hunter_robot" >
        <link name="base_link" />
    </xacro:macro>
</xacro:macro>
</robot>
```

and the content of generated urdf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<!-- |    This document was autogenerated by xacro from a.urdf.xacro                   | -->
<!-- |    EDITING THIS FILE BY HAND IS NOT RECOMMENDED                                 | -->
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
</robot>
```

I have faced this problem in two different machines.
any idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201208/xacro.py-generates-empty-urdf-file/) by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 717 on 2015-01-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`a.urdf.xacro` only defines the `hunter` xacro macro, but that macro is never called (and thus your robot never instantiated).

I typically create a 'top level' `.xacro` file for this (something like `hunter.xacro` fi) which is empty, apart from a call to the macro. In your case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="hunter" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  <xacro:include filename="$(find hunter_pkg)/a.urdf.xacro"/>
  <xacro:hunter/>
</robot>
```

Then convert / use as normal.

In my experience, keeping your xacro macro definitions separate makes it easier to include them in other, composite, xacros.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1